# SumIf using Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba

Can someone please help me with the sample data below. I'm creating a macro that will show the summary per primary key. I tried using SumIf but I'm getting Subscript out of range error.
[Raw Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WoVia.png)
**Raw Data**
Primary_Key   Quantity    Jan Price   Feb Price
123              2           30         35
123              1           40         45
123              2           45         50
456              5           20         25
456              3           30         35
456              4           25         30
789              2           50         55
789              1           60         65
789              3           65         70

[Summary](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XfdNu.png)
**Macro result**
Primary_Key Quantity    Jan Price   Feb Price
123            5           115        130
456            12           75         90
789            6           175        190

**--EDIT**

Thanks for the help. I decided to use pivot, then VBA to refresh the data source. However, I'm getting Type Mismatch error.

```
Sub CommandButton1_Click()

 Dim Data_sht As Worksheet
 Dim Pivot_sht As Worksheet
 Dim Start As Range
 Dim DataRange As Range
 Dim PivotName As String
 Dim NewRange As String

 Set Data_sht = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Raw Data")
 Set Pivot_sht = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Summary")

 PivotName = "Summary"

 Set Start = Data_sht.Range("A1")
 Set DataRange = Data_sht.Range(Start, 
 Start.SpecialCells(xlLastCell))

 NewRange = Data_sht.Name & "!" & _
 DataRange.Address(ReferenceStyle:=xlR1C1)

 Pivot_sht.PivotTables(PivotName).ChangePivotCache 
 ThisWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, _
 SourceData:=DataRange)

 Pivot_sht.PivotTables(PivotName).RefreshTable

 MsgBox PivotName & "'s data source range has been successfully 
 updated!"

End Sub
```

Comment: Please post your code.

Comment: Anyway this cries out for a pivot table.

Comment: **VERY** hard to tell what your problem is without being able to see the code.

Answer (score 0):

You may need to change the references as commented throughout my code, but this sub should do the trick for you. Also, I used sumif formulas, but if your raw dataset ever grows larger, I'd suggest to look into using collections instead as an efficiency measure.

```
Option Explicit

Sub SumByPK()

Dim dt As Object
Dim lastrow1 As Long
Dim lastrow2 As Long
Dim sh As Worksheet
Dim InputRng As Range
Dim OutRng As Range
Dim rng As Range
Dim qty, JanPrice, FebPrice As Double
Set dt = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
Set sh = Sheet1 'sheet object, change this if different

lastrow1 = sh.Cells(sh.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row 'determines last row, assuming there are no other data in A column but the primary keys.

Set InputRng = sh.Range("A2:A" & lastrow1) 'change the range ref in different
Set OutRng = sh.Range("G2") 'will output unique primary keys onto this range, change this if needed.
For Each rng In InputRng
    If rng.Value <> "" Then
    dt(rng.Value) = ""
    End If
Next rng

OutRng.Range("A1").Resize(dt.Count) = Application.WorksheetFunction.Transpose(dt.Keys)

lastrow2 = sh.Cells(sh.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row 'determines last row, assuming there are no other date in G column but the unique primary keys.

For Each rng In sh.Range("G2:G" & lastrow2) 'change the range reference if the OutRng has been changed.
    If rng.Value <> "" Then
        qty = Application.WorksheetFunction.SumIf(sh.Range("A2:A" & lastrow1), rng.Value, sh.Range(Cells(2, 2).Address & ":" & Cells(lastrow1, 2).Address))
        JanPrice = Application.WorksheetFunction.SumIf(sh.Range("A2:A" & lastrow1), rng.Value, sh.Range(Cells(2, 3).Address & ":" & Cells(lastrow1, 3).Address))
        FebPrice = Application.WorksheetFunction.SumIf(sh.Range("A2:A" & lastrow1), rng.Value, sh.Range(Cells(2, 4).Address & ":" & Cells(lastrow1, 4).Address))
        rng.Offset(0, 1).Value = qty
        rng.Offset(0, 2).Value = JanPrice
        rng.Offset(0, 3).Value = FebPrice
    End If
Next rng

End Sub�
�
```